# Number of n-dimensional vectors

Tags: combinatorics

I have a simple counting problem. Given the set of n-dimensional vectors over the natural numbers, how many vectors sum to exactly k?

I've tried counting it in two different ways:

1. I need to place k units into n bins. The first unit has n choices, the second - also n choices, etc, up to n^k options. I then divide by k! to account for the units being indistinguishable
2. This is analogous to the problem of placing k items between n-1 fences. The answer to this would be (k+n-1) choose k.

I'm not sure which one of those ideas is correct, and why. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: By natural numbers are you including $0$ or only the positives?

Comment: You may find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) helpful.

Comment: This is highly related to a question I asked yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3029324/algebraic-proof-that-binomnk-1k-sum-limits-i-0k-binomn-1k-i

Comment: @Pascal's Wager - yes, including zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counting problem is exactly the same as trying to find the number of natural number solutions to $x_1+...+x_n=k$ (I'm assuming $0$ is a natural number for our purposes.)

This is the same as, given $k$ items, the number of ways to separate them by placing $n-1$ fences in their midst.

Let i denote an item and | denote a fence.

Suppose for now $k=5$ and $n=3$.

ii|i|ii represents the solution $x_1=2, x_2=1,x_3=2$

i|iiii|| represents the solution $x_1=1,x_2=4,x_3=0$

As you can see, we have $k+(n-1)$ slots and we have to choose $k$ of them to be items. So there are $k+n-1 \choose k$ possibilties, so **your idea #2 is correct.**

---

Your idea #1 is incorrect, however, since ${k+n-1 \choose k} \neq \frac {n^k} {k!}$ when k=5 and n=3. In fact, in this case, $\frac {n^k} {k!}$ isn't even an integer!

Comment: Thanks,Now I also understand where I went wrong in my chain of thought with idea number 1.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{v}$ = <$x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$> be an $n$-dimensional vector whose entries sum to $k$. Then the number of such vectors corresponds to the number of solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = k$. By the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), the number of vectors is $\binom{k + n - 1}{k}$.